# Complete ZIPCode with PostCodeExtension have stopped working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, geocoding

I had an App in Apple store approved and it was working very fine, however, out of the blue, it has stopped working! I have used reverseGeocodeLocation and placemarks to get some information from "Address dictionary" and I perceived that the parameter "PostCodeExtension" seldom comes filled. This trouble started as soon as Apple launched the last version of IOS. Any clue?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you done to debug??

Comment: Hi, When I debug the aftermath is:

    2014-11-06 18:48:40.398 Ath[1575:1423037] Address dictionary: {
    City = "S\U00e3o Paulo";
    Country = Brazil;
    CountryCode = BR;
    FormattedAddressLines =     (
        "Rua Arandu, 122",
        "Itaim Bibi",
        "S\U00e3o Paulo - SP",
        04562,
        Brazil
    );
    Name = "Rua Arandu, 122";
    State = SP;
    Street = "Rua Arandu, 122";
    SubLocality = "Itaim Bibi";
    SubThoroughfare = 122;
    Thoroughfare = "Rua Arandu";
    ZIP = 04562;
    }

Comment: But, previously there was another parameter: "PostCodeExtension" and now it has vanished!